# Shader two outputs feedback

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I want to get two outputs from my shader, then feed them back into the shader to use as an iterator och accumulator. This works fine for the default "channel", but for two... So, here are the shaders:

```
#version 420
uniform sampler2DRect inData0;
uniform sampler2DRect inData1;
out float outData0;
out float outData1;
void main(void)
{
   outData0 = 1 + texture(inData0, gl_FragCoord.xy).r;
   outData1 = -1 + texture(inData1, gl_FragCoord.xy).r;
}
```

and

```
#version 420
in vec2 position;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
}
```

then the standard stuff

```
    Int32 frameBufferId = GL.GenFramebuffer();
    GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, frameBufferId);

    Int32 textureId0 = GL.GenTexture();
    GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.TextureRectangle, textureId0);
    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.TextureRectangle, 0, PixelInternalFormat.R32f, 1024, 1024, 0, PixelFormat.Red, PixelType.Float, new Single[1024 * 1024]);
    GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0, TextureTarget.TextureRectangle, textureId0, 0);

    Int32 textureId1 = GL.GenTexture();
    GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture1);
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.TextureRectangle, textureId1);
    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.TextureRectangle, 0, PixelInternalFormat.R32f, 1024, 1024, 0, PixelFormat.Red, PixelType.Float, new Single[1024 * 1024]);
    GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment1, TextureTarget.TextureRectangle, textureId1, 0);

    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.TextureRectangle, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (Int32)TextureMinFilter.Linear);

    Single[] arrayBufferData = new Single[4 * 2] { -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 };

    Int32 arrayBufferId = GL.GenBuffer();
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, arrayBufferId);
    GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(4 * 2 * sizeof(Single)), arrayBufferData, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    Int32 positionId = GL.GetAttribLocation(programId, "position");
    GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(positionId);
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(positionId, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
```

So, here is where I managed to get somewhere

```
    Single[] result = new Single[1024 * 1024];

    GL.**DrawBuffers**(2, new DrawBuffersEnum[] { DrawBuffersEnum.ColorAttachment0, DrawBuffersEnum.ColorAttachment1 });
    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads, 0, 4);

    GL.**ReadBuffer**(ReadBufferMode.ColorAttachment0);
    GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, 1024, 1024, PixelFormat.Red, PixelType.Float, result);

    GL.**ReadBuffer**(ReadBufferMode.ColorAttachment1);
    GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, 1024, 1024, PixelFormat.Red, PixelType.Float, result);
```

Which gives me both outputs properly. For one "channel", I'd call DrawArrays again and it would feed the output0 into input0, but here I want output1 to also go into input1. Is this doable? This R32f / Red is for testing -- they will be replaced by vec4.

Edit:
changed:

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2DRect inData0
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2DRect inData1
layout(location = 0) out float outData0;
layout(location = 1) out float outData1;
```

and it works.

Comment: you can output a vec4 from the fragment shader. the easiest thing is therefore probably to put your values into the red and green channel of that out vector and read it back in as a texture.

otherwise, have a look at multiple render targets, with which you can render to different textures (a technique that's very common, e.g. for deferred rendering). you can then set your textures to contain only an 8 bit value and thus not produce any overhead. if ultimately you will have more than four values, i'd still go the "one value per channel" route to reduce the number of textures

Comment: It would be great if you post your solution as the answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind input, and point the output to correct locatio.

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2DRect inData0
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2DRect inData1
layout(location = 0) out float outData0;
layout(location = 1) out float outData1;
```